# sonar maven plugin: Unable to scan non-existing project

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, sonarqube

I'm using sonarqube 4.5 with sonar-maven-plugin version 2.4. When I run maven sonar:sonar, I get the following error `Unable to scan non-existing project "Projectname"`. I previously used sonarqube 4.2 and I don't remember encountering such a problem. in my settings.xml for maven, i have the following profile

```
<profile>
        <id>sonar</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8</sonar.jdbc.url>
            <sonar.jdbc.username>username</sonar.jdbc.username>
            <sonar.jdbc.password>password</sonar.jdbc.password>
            <sonar.host.url>http://myserver:9000</sonar.host.url>
            <sonar.login>login</sonar.login>
            <sonar.password>password</sonar.password>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

This user has the following global permissions; Execute Analysis, Execute Preview Analysis and Provision Projects. the 'Provision Projects' permission states that `Ability to initialize project structure before first analysis.` and i imagine that this would allow the plugin to create the project in the sonar server before analysis. for sonarqube version 4.2 i never used to encounter this problem.

so the question is, how can i make the plugin create the project in the sonar server before running the analysis?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs, if your sonar user does not have the right to create new projects in sonar cube.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit? i mentioned the permissions given to this user

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the configuration value to false (from the sonar dashboard)

Setting -> Prevent automatic project creation = False

Answer (score 0):

A user with admin privileges needs to login to Sonar. From Settings > Provisioning needs to add the project details which are as follows:

1) Key: This is `<groupid>:<artifact id>` from your pom file. if you are planning to re-use the same project from your local machine then append user name to the key.

i.e `<groupid>:<artifact id>:<username>`

2) Name: This is the `<name>` tag value from the pom file.

After this is done, then if you run :

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.branch=$(whoami)
```

Note that the use of -Dsonar.branch=$(whoami) depends if you have provisioned with the username or not if not

```
mvn sonar:sonar
```

would suffice